# Accessing return value of a method call in Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have the below code where i would like to access the return value of `eventBasedExtractor.getSheets()` in order to do something in my test.
I tried spying, but did not give any result.

```
EventBasedExtractor eventBasedExtractor = EventBasedExcelExtractorFactory.create(file);
eventBasedExtractor.parse(file);
List<MyDto> worksheetClusterDtos = eventBasedExtractor.getSheets().stream()
      .map(sheet -> getMyDto(fileName, sheet))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is what i tried already (tried mock/spy):

```
EventBasedExtractor extractor = mock(EventBasedExtractor.class);
    doAnswer((Answer<List<Sheet>>) invocation -> {
        List<Sheet> sheets = (List<Sheet>) invocation.callRealMethod();
        for (Sheet sheet : sheets) {
            Row headerRow = sheet.rows().get(0);
            when(service.getHeaderRow(any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(headerRow));
        }
        return sheets;
    }).when(extractor).getProcessedSheets();
```

Comment: can you update the question and add the actual test? maybe you can do it slightly differently. I doubt `when(service.getHeaderRow(any())).thenReturn(...)` will work as expected if you initialize it in a loop